# enviar array en un input de un formulario

Tags: php, jquery

buenas estoy realizando lo que es un sistema de reporteria, y necesito enviar un array a un controlador php a traves del submit de un formulario  probe con esto

```
$('<form id="report" target="_blank"  method="POST" action="ajax/pdf.ajax.php"> '+'<input 
       type="hidden" name="data" value="' +jsonString +'">'+"
  </form>").appendTo("body");
 $("#report").trigger("submit");  
 $("#report").remove();
```

donde jsonString es una variable  `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(tabla);`  donde tabla es un array de objetos
y en mi controlador php `$data = $_POST['data'];` quiero recibirlo

pero solo me sale [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida

Comment: ¿y si haces un `console.log(jsonString)` que obtienes?

Comment: el valor de mi array [{"Dato1":"keyDAto1"},{"Dato1":"keyDAto1"},{"Dato1":"keyDAto1"}]

Comment: ¿y no contiene comillas ese valor de tu array?

Comment: A eso me refieria

Comment: si las tiene al inicio y al final

Comment: cuando pones eso dentro del `value=""` se estropea la petición porque ya es una cadena entrecomillada... lo que ya no se entiende es porque te sale lo del object, pero bueno.  Por si acaso puedes probar con `$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);` a ver si suena la flauta, pero lo dudo

Comment: O quizás, con un poco de suerte, si cambias el `value=""` por comillas simples así: `value=''` quizas te funcione (y lo del json_decode también déjalo puesto)

Comment: Y a malas, podrias mirar de escapar todas las comillas del json con un replace en javascript, y revertir eso cuando lo recibas en el PHP antes del json_decode.

Comment: gracias tenias razon eran la comillas

Comment: perfecto, si gustas postea tu mismo la respuesta con la solución, e indica tambien si has necesitado el json_decode o no al recibir el POST, asi la comunidad tambien lo sabrá, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gracias a @masterguru la respuesta era mas sencilla de lo que pense
simplemente era cambiar el escape de comillas

```
 $(
'<form id="report" target="_blank"  method="POST" action="ajax/pdf.ajax.php"> ' +
  "<input type='hidden' name='data' value='" +jsonString +"'>"+"</form>"
  ).appendTo("body");
```

y listo.